# In spring boot，how to transfer requests with different url prefix to different executors in tomcat by the prefix of url？

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, executor

So far，I know how to add one customized executor in tomcat. however，I have no idea assigning different executors for different request by url prefix. Hope your help!

the following is code example adding customized executor in tomcat:

```
@Component
public class EmbeddedTomcatConfig implements 
EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmbeddedTomcatConfig.class);

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        if(container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory){
            TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory)container;
            factory.addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
                @Override
                public void customize(Connector connector) {
                    AdvancedThreadExecutor myExecutor = 
new AdvancedThreadExecutor();
                    connector.getService().addExecutor(myExecutor);
                    ProtocolHandler handler = connector.getProtocolHandler();
                    Http11NioProtocol http11NioProtocol = (Http11NioProtocol)handler;
                    http11NioProtocol.setExecutor(myExecutor);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add more details on why you want to do that?

Comment: I have two kinds of APIs，the first type APIs usually takes 50ms to get responses from server A through Http protocol，the other APIs takes 400ms to get responses from server B. So i think they have different cpu wait time. In order to optimize my application performs. The max thread count in tomcat thread pool should be different?